# Eclipse RCP 3.x repopulating a ToolBar Combo from a Button Click in a Dialog

Tags: eclipse, combobox, triggers, toolbar, rcp

In an Eclipse RCP 3.x Application:

I have a Dialog - "User Settings" which contains a Button called "Set User".

The User Settings Dialog, creates and stores a list of User settings and saves them to a file.

In the Application's ToolBar I have a Combo (drop down) which lists these User details.

I would like the "Set User" Button inside the Dialog when Clicked to trigger an updateUsersCombo method which updates the ToolBar's User Combo contents with the updated list of Users, then selects that user in the combo.

I have the updateUsersCombo method worked out just fine... 
I simply need a means of calling (triggering) this method when the user clicks"Set User" button from an Open Dialog.

The User Dialog is a Title Area Dialog with SWT buttons.
User Combo is inside of a class extending WorkbenchWindowControlContribution which displays Users and some other settings in the Toolbar.

I'm fairly new to Eclipse 3.x.  Any help is much appreciated.

- Marv

Comment: You probably need to use the event broker `IEventBroker` to send and subscribe to events for these changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply greg-449.  Does Eclipse 3.x (not E4) have an event broker?

Comment: Assuming you are using an Eclipse 4 release the core of Eclipse is always e4. The 3.x compatability layer sits on top of that. In 3.x code you can use `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class)` to get the event broker.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compatibility layer is not part of the application.

Comment: If you are writing a 3.x RCP you are using the compatability layer - this is all the org.eclipse.ui plug-ins (unless you are using the obsolete Eclipse 3 series releases).